# Filter in dom-repeat is called only once

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to implement an auto complete component. I have a template with filter set:

```
<template id="resultList" is="dom-repeat" items="{{choices}}" filter="_listFilter">
    <paper-item>
        <paper-button on-tap="_selectItem">{{item}}</paper-button>
    </paper-item>
</template>
```

And the filter function:

```
_listFilter: function(item) {
    return item.toLowerCase().includes(
        this.value.toLowerCase()
    );
 },
```

So let's say the "choices" list is set to `['ABC', 'ADE', 'BCD']`.
Right now, if I type `A`, the filter works and shows me `ABC` and `ADE` in a drop down. However when I further type a `B` (the string is now `AB`), I would expect to see only `ABC` in the drop down now but I still see both `ABC` and `ADE` . Essentially the filter only runs on the first input.

How do I get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what I was looking for:
https://jcrowther.io/2015/06/09/polymer-dom-repeat-filtering-and-sorting/